# Get php variable from server to client

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sqlite

I have been in the process of writing an app with Phonegap and one aspect I want my app to include is the ability to read variables from a PHP file on my server that are created by the PHP reading from an SQLite3 database. I have gotten the PPH and SQLite3 to work together. However I can not understand how to use either JQuery/Ajax/Javascript to display the value of the serverside PHP variable on the clientside index.html file.

Some code I have tried:

ClientSide HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://5.175.191.73/test.php",
      dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
      success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
        alert(data.test1);
        //parse the json data
      }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

ServerSide PHP

```
<?php

$test = array();
$test['test1'] = '1';
$test['test2'] = '2';
$test['test3'] = '3';

echo json_encode($test);

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: `json_encode` produces `string`. Try `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data); alert(parsedData.test1);`

Comment: I changed the JS code to include `var phpArray = JSON.parse(data);` and `alert(phpArray.test1)` however it still does not work, am I doing something wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

```
var phpArray = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then just use `phpArray.test1` to get the value for test 1 in your php array.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the javascript code to 
`<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://fusion.mine.bz/test.php",
      dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
      success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
   var phpArray = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(phpArray.test1);
        //parse the json data
      }
    });
</script>`

But it still does not work, I am rather new to javascript in general.

Comment: Any help you could give me would be very much appreciated